# Viewmodel.observe зациклился

Tags: android, kotlin, sqlite, viewmodel, observer

```
val listshCode2 = ArrayList<ScanModel>()
                try {

                    viewModel.getByShCode(edShtrih.text.toString())
                        .observe(this@Scan) { listshCode1 ->
                            listshCode2.addAll(listshCode1)

                            if (listshCode2.isEmpty()) {
                                viewModel.insert(
                                    ScanModel(
                                        shCode = edShtrih.text.toString().trim(),
                                        countNo = edCount.text.toString().trim(),
                                        dokNo = getDockNum.trim()
                                    )
                                ) {}
                            } else {
                                val sum =
                                    listshCode2.last().countNo.toInt() + edCount.text.toString().toInt()

                                viewModel.update(
                                    ScanModel(
                                        id = listshCode2.last().id,
                                        shCode = edShtrih.text.toString(),
                                        countNo = sum.toString(),
                                        dokNo = getDockNum.trim()

                                    )
                                ) {}

                            }
                        }
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    Log.e("vm getByShcode", e.toString())
                }
```

После того как он сделал запрос Insert или Update он возвращается к запросу getByShCode и идет по кругу. Как можно сделать что бы он один раз делал запрос.

Comment: Наверное у вас идёт в getByShCode постоянный поток данных. Покажите как он реализован

Comment: @ЮрийСПб ScanViewModel
 `fun getByShCode(shCode3: String): LiveData<List<ScanModel>> {
        return REPOSITORY.getShCodeInScans(shCode3)
    }`
ScanRepository 
``fun getShCodeInScans(shCode3: String): LiveData<List<ScanModel>>``
ScanRealization
``override fun getShCodeInScans(shCode3: String): LiveData<List<ScanModel>> {
        return scanDao.getShCodeInScan(shCode3)
    }``
ScanDao
`@Query("SELECT * FROM scan_table " +
            "WHERE shCode = :shCode3")
    fun getShCodeInScan(shCode3: String): LiveData<List<ScanModel>>`
`

Comment: Код лучше в сам вопрос добавлять, а не в комментарий - так сохранится форматирование и код будет читаемым. У вас явно написано так, чтобы на любое изменение в таблице источник данных излучал обновлённые данные. Если вам это не надо - просто не используйте LiveData. Пусть метод Dao возвращает просто `List<ScanModel>`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Спасибо за советы, в следующий раз учту. Попробую сделать как вы сказали, после напишу.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Спасибо большое, получилось!